# Having trouble when loading class through another extended class in PHP

Tags: php

I have three class: **A**, **B** and **C**.
In class **A**, A.php:

```
class A
{
    function __Contruct()
    {
          //do something
    }
}
```

In class **B**, B.php:

```
class B extends A
{
    function __Contruct()
    {
         //do something
    }
}
```

In class **C**:

```
class C
{
    function __Contruct()
    {
         include(A.php);
         $this->A = new A;
         include(B.php);
         $this->B = new B;
    }
    function _load()
    {
         //load class $X;
    }
}
```

I need to load a class whose name is value of a variable:$X to class without word **new** in class B.

Can I do it this way:`$this->classname->functionname();//classname is value of $X` in file B.php.

Comment: Can you please tell us where $X is declared?

Comment: Your `include` statements don't make sense. You can't have a class declaration inside another class declaration. You should put these statements at the top-level, not inside the class.

Comment: Oh! I think I make some mistake when do that! Thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

You extend class B with class A, so why didn't you extend class C with class B?
Then you can access all properties & methods of class A and class B.

No need of

```
$this->classname->functionname();
```

or you can access method or property as follows,

```
A::functionname();
B::functionname();
C::functionname();
```

Comment: Thanks but I need to do "$this->classname->functionname();":D! And I can't extends class C because this 's behind process class. I want to hide it!

Comment: Please anyone help me! I'm going crazy:(!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want are:

```
$var = new $X;
```

to create an instance of class `$X` and

```
$X::functionname()
```

to call a method of class `$X`.

UPDATE:

If $this->classname returns the name of a class, maybe what you need is:

```
($this->classname)::functionname();
```

Comment: Thanks but it's not what i want to do!:)
Please see my comment below!