# Reference an object of extended class in PHP

Tags: php, class, reference

I have 3 class names:"**ClassA**", "**ClassB**","**ClassC**".

**ClassB** extends **ClassA**. **ClassC.php** included **ClassA.php** and then **ClassB.php**.

I have an array **$arrayA** in **ClassC**:`var $arrayA;`

How can I do below things?

_ When I make an instance of **ClassC** in **ClassA** as:`$this->ClassC`,

**$arrayA** in **ClassA** as:`$this->ClassC->arrayA`,

**arrayA**'s value was changed through process of **ClassC** and `$this->ClassC->arrayA` 's value was changed too!

_ Call `$this->ClassC->arrayA` as an object in **ClassA**.

_ Use it in class B.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Could you post some actual code showing what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Also, let's be *very* intentional about our words in technical contexts. The phrase "ClassC included ClassA and then ClassB" is meaningless, as classes do not "include" things. Do you mean "extends"? Or just that the file ClassC is defined in does a PHP include of the files A and B are defined in?

Comment: Oh sorry! I mean ClassC.php included ClassA.php! I'm so sorry about that mistake

Answer (score 1):

If I follow correctly, the essence of the answer is that objects are not "copied" in each context which references them, they are "pointed to".

Lets say you have a Person object, and that person has a property called "hometown" which is an instance of Town. In very generalized pseudo-code:

```
Town->name = "Portland";
Person->hometown = Town;
Person->hometown->name = "Detroit";
echo Town->name;

// output is "Detroit"
```

Comment: Thanks man! I found another way to do things I posted above, but it is not my wish(I talking about my way,don't misunderstand:D). 
I hope it like this: [link about it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12120443/having-trouble-when-loading-class-throught-another-extended-class-in-php)